# Rest Api in magento2?

Tags: magento2.2

**Magento 2, Why we use data folder in api?
Use of data folder in api**

If anyone knows please explain me
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Api directory have repositories.
It Contains set of code that third-party developers can call, implement, or build as a plug-in. Magento guarantees that this code will not change in subsequent releases without a major version change.

In general, the purpose of a repository is to hide the storage related logic.

Api/Data contains the Data Model Interfaces. These have getter and setter functions.

For more details you can go through following links : 
http://vinaikopp.com/2017/02/18/magento2_repositories_interfaces_and_webapi/
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/api-concepts.html

Answer (score 0):

It's part of the Magento 2 Service Layer.

Your code should depend of abstractions not concrete implementations.
This makes the code more extensible and flexible.

From the Magento 2 docs
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/architecture/archi_perspectives/service_layer.html

Related Topics

**Dependency Injection** and **Dependency Inversion**.

The topic is big and this answer is brief the guide provided above should offer more perspective on the matter.